# How to get all managed accounts and create a new one using PowerShell in SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, 2013, managed-account

I need to get all Managed Accounts in SharePoint 2013. If there are nothing, I need to create a new one. How can I do this using PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return a list of managed accounts:

```
Get-SPManagedAccount
```

To create a new managed account:

```
$appPoolUserName = "<domain>\<user_name>"
$appPoolCred = Get-Credential $appPoolUserName
New-SPManagedAccount -Credential $appPoolCred
```

Answer (score 1):

just take a look at: https://www.windegger.wtf/sharepoint-2013-managed-accounts-2/ the post contains pretty detailed Information about createing the Managed Accounts for SharePoint 2010/2013 the first post in that series also contains a PowerShell script to create the ActiveDirectory Accounts that are used for the Managed Accounts

Bye